# log4j2 configuration per Apache Storm topology

Tags: log4j2, apache-storm

Is it possible to include log4j2 configuration per topology loaded into Apache Storm?

I know it is possible to toggle the log level per topology, but I need to see if I can apply specific configuration to each.  I've looked into the settings in `storm.yaml` and there are some for setting the location (`storm.log4j2.conf.dir`), but this file seems to be overall Storm specific, rather topology specific.  Can you apply a `storm.yaml` per topology?

I've also tried adding the log4j2 JVM arg ( `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=classpath:log4j2.xml`) when loading the jar but this doesn't override it either.  This `log4j2.xml` file is included in my JARs

Apache Storm v1.2.4

**EDIT**

From http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Configuration.html :

> Every configuration has a default value defined in defaults.yaml in the Storm codebase. You can override these configurations by defining a storm.yaml in the classpath of Nimbus and the supervisors. ***Finally, you can define a topology-specific configuration that you submit along with your topology when using StormSubmitter. However, the topology-specific configuration can only override configs prefixed with "TOPOLOGY".***

So I guess from this, and that none of the `topology.*` configs in defaults.yaml (https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/conf/defaults.yaml) have any connection with log configurations, means that what I'm looking for cannot be done.

**EDIT 2**

So it looks like as of Apache Storm v2.0.0, you can include a log4j2 config file in topology JARs and set a new storm configuration `topology.logging.config.file`.
https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.3.0/javadocs/org/apache/storm/Config.html#TOPOLOGY_LOGGING_CONFIG_FILE

Comment: Could you try this config.file on topology level? Did it work?

Comment: @moosehead42 No, I'm stuck on v1.2.4.  That was introduced in v2.0.0